# Python setup script extensions, how do you include a .h file?

Tags: python, c, installation, setup.py

So I've got a directory that looks something like this:

```
 home\
     setup.py
     some_python_file.py
     ext\
         __init__.py
         c_file1.c
         c_file2.c
         ext_header.h
```

Obviously the header file is necessary to compile the c files, but the problem is that I can't get the setup script to include the header file.

My extension object is something like this:

```
Extension('ext.the_extension', ['ext/c_file1.c', 'ext/c_file2.c'])
```

Which works, but doesn't include the header file.  If I change it to:

```
Extension('ext.the_extension', ['ext/c_file1.c', 'ext/c_file2.c', 'ext_header.h'])
```

It includes the '.h' file but then doesn't build when I run install.  Instead it gives and error `error: unknown file type '.h' (from 'ext/ext_header.h')`

If I include the header file as a data file like this:

```
data_files=[('ext', ['ext/ext_header.h'])]
```

it doesn't work at all, the .h file doesn't even make it into the MANIFEST file.

So my queustion is, how do you include this extension with the header file so that `python setup.py install` will build it correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a feeling pyfunc is on track for a more standard solution, but I did find another solution on my own.  I have no idea if this is a good solution or just a hack, but all I did is add the header file to the MANIFEST.in.  The documentation doesn't really make it seem like this is what the MANIFEST.in file is for, but it does work.  My MANIFEST.in file now looks like this:

```
include ext/ext_header.h
```

Which includes the file and sucessfully compiles when I run `python setup.py install`

Comment: if you have more header files 'include ext/*.h' would have worked as well. Please mark this (yes your own answer) as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs,

```
module1 = Extension('demo',
                define_macros = [('MAJOR_VERSION', '1'),
                                 ('MINOR_VERSION', '0')],
                include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include'],
                libraries = ['tcl83'],
                library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib'],
                sources = ['demo.c'])
```

You should provide the include files via "include_dirs".

Why does this not work for you?

Comment: I think this might be the right path but I'm a bit confused as to what is going on.  Doesn't the include_dir variable just tell the compiler where to look for header files?  How would this result in my .h file making it into the MANIFEST?

Comment: `include dirs` tells the compiler where to look for the standard header files you include with `<>`, for example `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, etc. In case the setup script doesn't want to package your own header files, I think you are not supposed to have custom header files in a Python extension.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: Both standard and custom headers files are pointed to in location - include\_dirs

Comment: I just tried this and couldn't get it to work, the .h file still doesn't make it to the MANIFEST.  Does it assume the person receiving the distrobution already has a copy of the header file?  What I really need is for the header file to be included with the distribution.

Comment: @user411133: your own solution below to edit MANIFEST.in to include header should work.  That is not a hack. It is the solution.